# Unable to upload new APK file to Android Play store even though debug is off

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I am trying to upload an `APK` to Google Play store. I have added `android:debuggable="false"` in the `application` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml`. But, still it says you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play.

Update:
I am using debug.keystore for signing the APK. So, is it the reason for the issue ?
Should I create a different release.keystore ?

Comment: clean your project then make signed apk or remove android:debuggable from manifest

Comment: I have cleaned and signed the apk. I didn't add android:debuggable="false" in manifest tag, I added it in application tag.

Comment: You needn't add android:debuggable="false" in the manifest. Please run the application in normal mode and sign the apk and try.

Comment: right click on project->Android Tools->run lint: check for common errors

Comment: Did you change version of apk or not?

Comment: Trying to upload the first APK, so default it's `android:versionCode="1"` and `android:versionName="1.0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're signing your application with the release key (not the debug key).

Comment: Yes, I think I should try creating a release.keystore and try to sign the APK.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are right.

To Put your application on Google Play Store You have to generate release.keystore.

Please check the steps of how to generate keystore ::

1. Right click the project.
2. Go to Android Tools.
3. select Export Signed APK Package.
4. Enter Project Name.
5. Select create new key store option.
6. Set Location eg: Keystore Location.

At the end of this procedure you will have you build.apk and put that APK on Play Store that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use a release key, you can not upload to the play store if your app is signed with the debug key.  See http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all calls to the catlog in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Look for `BuildConfig.java` in your source dir and see what it says for DEBUG.

If you're using Gradle/Android Studio be sure to select the `release` variant.

If you using Eclipse, disable auto-build, do a clean, then use the `Export signed APK` option in Android Tools.